# Microsoft Store failing to update or download

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-store

I'm having trouble with Microsoft Store. When I'm trying to update my apps, I get a failed error (0x80070015) and no update. I've come across the following article (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store-winpc/windows-store-error-code-0x80070015/6e74a78a-1e18-4141-813b-031dac3a4d36) which seems to do no good. Short of re-installing Windows, does anyone have any experience or suggestions to remedy this problem?

This is on Windows 10 1803

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the same issue before.

I have seen the same error code in the link:[How to Fix Windows Store Install Error 0x80070015](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-windows-store-install-error-0x80070015-something-went-wrong/)

There are several methods, they could be helpful.

1. **Clear Store Cache**
   (1) press `win + R`
   (2) type `wsreset.exe` and press enter
2. **Windows Store Apps Troubleshooter**
   (1) open **Control Panel**
   (2) click **small icon** on the right-top
   (3) find and click **troubleshooting**
   (4) click **view all** on the left panel
   (5) then find and run the **windows store app**
3. **Windows Update Troubleshooter**
   It is the same steps as the windows store app troubleshooter, but right-click it and run it as administrator.
4. **Clean boot**
   This has been included in the link you posted.
5. **Unload Power ISO Virtual Drive Manager**
   (1) run the **task manager**
   (2) click **details**
   (3) find **Power ISO** related processes
   (4) end them

Hope above information can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response OOOO. I tried resetting Windows Store via the Settings menu but this did nothing as far as I could tell. This error was also affecting Windows Updates and preventing them from being installed. I've now resolved the problem by performing a complete clean installation of Windows, life is much better now!

Comment: Anyway, I am glad to hear the issue has gone.

Answer (score 1):

I have had to perform a clean installation of Windows as I found this error was also preventing Windows Updates from downloading/installing.

Things are now peachy.

Comment: everybody says to do this, but really what happens during that reset that makes it work again? this is what we are trying to figure out.